# windows 10 ip route not working for modem usb 3G

Tags: windows, ip, gateway, route, interface

i have 2 interfaces:

1 .- Cable ethernet

2 .- USB modem 3G,

The problem is i cannot work with both at same time, routing seems not to be working for me...

I cannot nake this work:

```
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.39.232.98     10.39.232.97    257
```

This is  my ipconfig/all:
C:\Users\Indra>ipconfig /all

```
Configuración IP de Windows
   Nombre de host. . . . . . . . . : JATAUJEPW10
   Sufijo DNS principal  . . . . . :
   Tipo de nodo. . . . . . . . . . : híbrido
   Enrutamiento IP habilitado. . . : no
   Proxy WINS habilitado . . . . . : no
Adaptador de banda ancha móvil Red celular:
   Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
   Descripción . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : HUAWEI Mobile Connect - Network Card
   Dirección física. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-1E-10-1F-00-00
   DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : no
   Configuración automática habilitada . . . : sí
Adaptador de Ethernet Ethernet:
   Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
   Descripción . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Dirección física. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10-E7-C6-E2-B4-4B
   DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : no
   Configuración automática habilitada . . . : sí
```

When i have only one connection my route looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Indra>route print
===========================================================================
ILista de interfaces
  2...00 1e 10 1f 00 00 ......HUAWEI Mobile Connect - Network Card
 12...10 e7 c6 e2 b4 4b ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Tabla de enrutamiento
===========================================================================
Rutas activas:
Destino de red        Máscara de red   Puerta de enlace   Interfaz  Métrica
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0      En vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255      En vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      En vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      En vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      En vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
===========================================================================
Rutas persistentes:
  Ninguno

IPv6 Tabla de enrutamiento
===========================================================================
Rutas activas:
 Cuando destino de red métrica      Puerta de enlace
  1    331 ::1/128                  En vínculo
  1    331 ff00::/8                 En vínculo
===========================================================================
Rutas persistentes:
  Ninguno
```

When i connect my usb modem my table gets modified this way:

```
C:\Users\Indra>route print
===========================================================================
ILista de interfaces
  2...00 1e 10 1f 00 00 ......HUAWEI Mobile Connect - Network Card
 12...10 e7 c6 e2 b4 4b ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Tabla de enrutamiento
===========================================================================
Rutas activas:
Destino de red        Máscara de red   Puerta de enlace   Interfaz  Métrica
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.39.232.98     10.39.232.97    257
     10.39.232.96  255.255.255.252      En vínculo      10.39.232.97    257
     10.39.232.97  255.255.255.255      En vínculo      10.39.232.97    257
     10.39.232.99  255.255.255.255      En vínculo      10.39.232.97    257
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0      En vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255      En vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      En vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      En vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      En vínculo      10.39.232.97    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      En vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      En vínculo      10.39.232.97    257
===========================================================================
Rutas persistentes:
  Ninguno

IPv6 Tabla de enrutamiento
===========================================================================
Rutas activas:
 Cuando destino de red métrica      Puerta de enlace
  1    331 ::1/128                  En vínculo
  2    257 fe80::/64                En vínculo
  2    257 fe80::c010:5eea:be6b:ad4e/128
                                    En vínculo
  1    331 ff00::/8                 En vínculo
  2    257 ff00::/8                 En vínculo
===========================================================================
Rutas persistentes:
  Ninguno
```

Additionally here is my  Get-NetIPInterface (Ethernet appears disconnected so i can post this)

```
ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
2       Red celular                     IPv6                  1500               1 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv6            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
12      Ethernet                        IPv4                  1500               2 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
2       Red celular                     IPv4                  1500               1 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv4            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not support Equal-cost multi-path routing. You cannot set the default gateway with the same metric to two different interfaces.